# Changing the ViewModel used by a LayoutAwarePage

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8

In my Windows 8 App, I have a few UserControls that I've created my own ViewModels for and wired them up. For my main page, the default ViewModel created by `LayoutAwarePage` has been good enough, but now I want to do a bit more like add some commands and other properties. I would like to create a simple ViewModel for my `MainPage` that is currently inheriting from `LayoutAwarePage`, but I'm concerned I'll break some of the included features such as rotation handling etc. The `LayoutAwarePage` and the `DependencyProperty` it creates for the default ViewModel appear to be so tightly coupled I'm concerned I'll break something if I futz with it (if you've read the ReadMe.txt in the Common folder, perhaps you understand my concerns).

Any tips on how to proceed?

thanks!

Comment: The LayoutAwarePage is a View, your ViewModel should not extend from a View

Comment: I suppose I can reword this to be clearer, and perhaps I will. Yes, LayoutAwarePage is a view, but it creates a DependencyProperty "DefaultViewModel". They seem so tightly coupled that I don't want to break one by removing the other.

Comment: I would suggest removing that property and just using your own VM for your needs. Much cleaner that way. Remember, LayoutAwarePage is merely a sample, and not intended to be "the gospel" of how you should do it